# Deriving class from class that is using generic of derived class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I do not understand why does this code work.
Derived class is inheriting from Base class that is using Derived class type.
I would have expect some king of infinite loop in type creation.

Please can someone explain why does this code work?
Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.Console;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine(new Derived(new Internal<Derived>()));

            ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Base<T>
    {
        public Base(Internal<T> intern)
        {
            this.Intern = intern;
        }

        public Internal<T> Intern { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Internal<T>
    {
    }

    public class Derived : Base<Derived>
    {
        public Derived(Internal<Derived> intern)
            : base(intern)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Derived` class seems like just an abstraction. It's like deriving `class IntegerList : List<int>`. As a side node, your example does not seem to fit into any regular coding patterns and is therefore hard to understand. Typically this means that the approach may not be optimal.

Comment: Why would it _not_ work? I mean, what is the question here, what answer do you expect?

Comment: Can you explain why you think it would cause an infinite loop in detail? Then we can see where you have a misunderstanding and point it out to you.

Comment: @Sweeper Derived will inherit from Base<Derived>. I order to create Base<Derived> you need to have Derived, so then you would create Derived inheriting Base<Derived> etc. How is Base<Derived> being created before Derived?

Answer (score 2):

From your comment:

> `Derived` will inherit from `Base<Derived>`. In order to create `Base<Derived>` you need to have `Derived`, so then you would create `Derived` inheriting `Base<Derived>` etc. How is `Base<Derived>` being created before `Derived`?

Your misunderstanding starts from here here:

> In order to create `Base<Derived>` you need to have `Derived`

That is not true. You might think that to create `T<U>` you must need an instance of `U` first.

Take `List<string>` as an example. I can create an `List<int>` without using any instances of `string`:

```
var list = new List<string>();
```

`list` does not contain any `string`s. It's just an empty list. The same thing applies here.

To create a `Base<Derived>`, you need an `Internal<Derived>`, which you have by doing `new Internal<Derived>()`. `Internal<Derived>` also does not require an instance of `Derived` to be created by the same logic.

What is really happening here is you are trying to create an instance of `Derived`. You call its constructor, which calls `Base<Derived>`'s constructor with an instance of `Internal<Derived>`.

> How is `Base<Derived>` being created before `Derived`?

If you think about it, it kind of makes sense to have base classes created before derived classes. To create a `Cat`, you create an `Animal` first, and then you add all the `Cat`-specific features to it.